# Stuck in infinite loop searching through text boxes

Tags: vba, excel

My code searches through the entire worksheet searching for a text box that matches the phrase entered. Pressing yes goes to the next response with that phrase no will copy the current text box. My problem is it does not search through the entire work sheet but gets stuck looping through one worksheet until I press no to copy. I am new to VBA so please any help would be thankful.

```
Sub FindResponse()
    Dim rStart As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sFind As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim Response
    Dim obj As New DataObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet




    sFind = InputBox("Search for?")
    If Trim(sFind) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Nothing entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rStart = ActiveCell

    For Each ws In Worksheets


    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With shp
        sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
        If InStr(LCase(sTemp), LCase(sFind)) <> 0 Then
            shp.Select
            Response = MsgBox( _
              prompt:=shp.Name & vbCrLf & _
              sTemp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "Yes to see other matches: No to copy text", _
              Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Continue?")
            If Response <> vbYes Then

            obj.SetText sTemp
            obj.PutInClipboard

                Exit Sub

            End If

        End If
        End With
    Next shp

    Next ws

 On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox "Value not found"

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no other error handling in this subroutine.  Why is there an `On Error` command at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your loop is something like this:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
  For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With shp
      ...
    End With
  Next shp
Next ws
```

As you may guess after having had a closer look at it, the reason it stays on the same sheet is that in your inner loop, you loop through `ActiveSheet.Shapes`, instead of `ws.Shapes`, which I suspect is what you intend to do.

I am a bit surprised to hear that the loop is infinite though - could it be that it just loops through the sheet you invoke it from the same number of times as there are sheets in the workbook?

Comment: It might have looped through them all but I do have like 200 so I did not go through all 200.

Comment: Ah, of course. Did switching `ActiveSheet` to `ws` work?

Comment: I do have a question though when trying to run through them now I get an error saying" Object doesn't support this property or method" after running through the first text box found. When I debug it highlights this line of code sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text

Comment: That is how you refer to the text in a textbox? Too lazy to google it myself right now. If that is the case, my best guess is that you've run across a different shape which doesn't contain those properties. Try to add an if-statement which checks if the current shape is a textbox

Comment: Thank you so much it was because of the title page so I just made an If to skip the active page which is the title page where the macro button will be. If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then   Thank you again so much I would be pulling my hair out over it.

Comment: You could also have done something like `If sh.Type = msoTextBox Then`, in the innermost loop, but what works, works, I guess :) It also saves you from looping through one sheet. If you found the answer satisfactory, I would appreciate it if you marked it as such, by clicking the accepted-checkmark next to the top of the question (under the arrows)